# Can element occur in a CNF formula?

Tags: boolean-algebra

For example, is $(X \vee 1)$ a valid formula in conjunctive normal form (CNF)?

If yes, then I would have to consider such formulas when trying to prove a statement about all CNF formulas.

Comment: This could depend on your definition of CNF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$X \vee 1$ is not a CNF formula because $1$ is neither a variable nor the negation of a variable. Both $X$ and $\neg X$ are valid CNF formulas, however.

Comment: The question is not hurting anyone.